# Create docker image running old Windows version

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, docker-container, docker-image, docker-build

I am new to docker and my task is to create docker container running Windows 98.
The difficult part is not having Windows 98 installed. My computer has Windows 7/Kubuntu 16 (dual boot).
I am looking for some way of getting ready Windows98 docker image or creating it using these operational systems.

P.S. I think I need to clarify: I prefer to run docker over Kubuntu, not Windows (if possible).
The docker image should run Windows98 inside.

Answer (score 5):

[Here](https://hub.docker.com/u/microsoft/) you can find official images from Microsoft for docker.
As you can see there are only Nano Server and Windows Server Core containers available.

Unfortunately for Windows98, you would need to use regular VM.

Comment: Probably I could buy Windows98 image from somewhere?

Comment: Microsoft is not selling Win98 anymore. Probably only way to get a genuine licence for Win98 is to buy it on places like Ebay (if you could find it).